# force cli bash write to csv file

Tags: bash, csv, command-line-interface

I need to export sobjects from a salesforce org using force cli in bash. Can someone point out some examples? I need to export to a csv file. It works with a simple query like:

```
force query Select Id FROM Account > account.csv
```

But I need to export all account fields with a WHERE clause. That's when it doesn't work.

```
Select Id, IsDeleted, MasterRecordId, Name, LastName, FirstName, Salutation, Type, RecordTypeId, ParentId, Phone, Fax, Website, PhotoUrl, NumberOfEmployees, Ownership, Description, Rating, OwnerId, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp, LastActivityDate, MayEdit, IsLocked, LastViewedDate, LastReferencedDate, IsExcludedFromRealign, PersonContactId, IsPersonAccount. . . FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate >= 2017-04-17T00:00:00z > account.csv
```

It doesn't work. --> 
FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate 2017-04-17T00:00:00z
                              ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:4268
unexpected token: '2017-04-17T00:00:00z'

It has something to do with ">=" not being recognized, but I'm not sure of what the correct syntax is. If someone could give me some pointers on how to run complex queries and export sobject data to a csv file it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks but I get a similar error:
FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate ‘2017-04-17T00:00:00z’
                              ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:4268
line 1:4268 no viable alternative at character '‘'

It doesn't recognize ">=".

Comment: Oh yes. I see that now: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

Comment: It suggests [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm) that the format for datetime literals is different when used in a `WHERE` clause. Their example is `2011-04-26T10:00:00-08:00` It doesn't elaborate on what `different` means though: "You can use date or datetime values, or date literals. The format for date and dateTime fields are different."

Comment: My original syntax works with dataloader but not in force cli.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:
`WHERE CreatedDate \>\= 2017-04-17T00:00:00z > account.csv`

Needed to escape >=.
Thanks!